# Unable to transfer my sensor data or file from one ROS machine to another vai ethernet

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, ubuntu, multiple, ethernet

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am trying to transfer sensor data which is connected to one of ROS machine, and transferring the live sensor data to my other ROS machine over ethernet. But i'm not getting how to do it. I'm new to this. Any tutorials or materials with example or hands on would help me a lot. C or pyhton any coding language is fine, I'm using Kinetic Kame version with Ubuntu 16.04

Thanks,
Chabbi

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/281332/unable-to-transfer-my-sensor-data-or-file-from-one-ros-machine-to-another-vai-ethernet/) by [Chabbi](https://answers.ros.org/users/33488/chabbi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-01-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's a tutorial about running ROS on multiple machines here: http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/MultipleMachines

There's also a network debugging guide here: http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/NetworkSetup

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2018-01-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0